# Example of a ring with prime characteristic, which is not an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We know that every intgral domain has prime (or 0) characteristic. Is there en example that the converse isn't true? Does there exist a ring, which is not an integral domain, but has a prime characteristic?

Answer (score 7):

$\frac{\mathbb Z}{\mathbb Zp}\times\frac{\mathbb Z}{\mathbb Zp}\,.$ For the characteristic $0$ case, consider $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R\,.$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course. Take $\mathbb{F}_p[t]/(t^2)$.

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ are polynomials over given field $\mathbb{F}$ that has p elements, like $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: @user19502: Yes, exactly. $\mathbb{F}_p$ is another notation for the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.