# Give an example of a ring with characteristic 23 but is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, arithmetic

I know that Z mod 23 would have characteristic 23, but this is a field since 23 is prime. How can I go about solving this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535155/example-of-a-ring-with-prime-characteristic-which-is-not-an-integral-domain) may be of interest

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider $\Bbb Z_{23}\times \Bbb Z_{23}$.

You know there is a certain multiplication that makes this a field.  Perhaps you could find some other multiplication operation that is not quite so nice?

Answer (score 1):

Ring of polynomes  (Z/23Z)[x^2 - 2*x + 1] as example

x-1 is a zero divizor